# Google Maps API v2 on iOS always show last map view before

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps API v2 with PhoneGap to develop both Android and iOS application. For that purpose i am using PhoneGap plugin that implements native device Google Maps app rather then JavaScript API.

In iOS when i load/show map it first shows last visited location for half a second then it goes to place i set with setCenter or moveCamera. And if there isn't any last visited location (app is started for the first time) map starts from 0,0 coordinates.
In Android everything works fine, when i set certain location it doesn't show anything before that.

I have tried every method there is and nothing works, and i am starting to think that this is default behavior in Google Maps SDK for iOS. But its so bad and makes using maps so confusing that its hard for me to believe there isn't way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add cookies function , IOS sometimes specially when using maps dosnt allow that , except those who will allow the cookies, thia would work if its in browser but not natively. Moreover, even if you use phonegape build , it only complie files that Apache understand,  meaning you wont be eligable to use ruby files or other files that only supported by the service.